# php-how to check both empty array and key without value at the same time in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$marks=array( 
            "mohammad" => array (
               "physics" => array([0]=>35,[1]=>45)
               "maths" => 30,   
               "chemistry" => 39
            ),

            "qadir" => array (
               "physics" => array(),
               "maths" => 32,
               "chemistry" => 29
            ),

            "zara" => array (
               "physics" => array([0]=>),
               "maths" => 22,
               "chemistry" => 39
            )
         );
```

In the above array, "physics" element has array of values in "mohammad",empty array in "qadir" and in "Zara" it has index [0] with no value.

How can we check for "physics" is empty array or empty value for first index?

I have tried in if loop like below:

```
$name ='qadir'
if(!empty($marks[$name]['physics'])){//do here}
```

The above code working fine for 'qadir' but not for 'Zara'.I wish to check both cases at the same time.

Please suggest your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). This will remove any empty values from the array which will check the empty condition correctly. Something like:

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($marks[$name]['physics']);
if(!empty($filteredArray)) {//do here}
```

Comment: ,it is working fine..but in my php editor it showing error `Arbitrary expressions in empty is allowed only in php 5.5`..But my php version is 5.5.12

Comment: Hi..It is working fine..I have question why it is not working out if filter with whole array like `array_filter($marks)`.

Comment: PHP manual says `empty — Determine whether a **variable** is empty` and array_filter is a function call not a variable - Kindly accept this answer if this resolved your issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!empty($marks[$name]['physics']) || !isset($marks[$name]['physics'][0])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code for null check in array

```
if(!empty($marks[$name]['physics']){
   if(!in_array(null, $haystack, true)){
     //do here
   }
}
```